# How to Get File Path from URI in Android Oreo (8.1) or above

Tags: android, uri, android-contentresolver, android-fileprovider, android-8.1-oreo

**Expected Behavior**

When I am selecting the file which is stored inside "Download", it should able to retrieves its file name and path

**Actual Behavior**

When I am selecting the file which is stored inside "Download", it returns null.

**Steps to Reproduce the Problem**

1. When picking file method is called, it displays the folders in Android
2. Go to downloads, select a file
3. It returns null in getting real path from URI

> Here is the code what i implemented

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
   String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
   if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
      if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
          return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
      }
      try {
         final boolean isOreo = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O;
         String stringContentURI;
         Uri contentUri;
         if(isOreo){ 
            stringContentURI = "content://downloads/my_downloads";
         }else{
            stringContentURI = "content://downloads/public_downloads";
         }
         contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse(stringContentURI), Long.valueOf(id));
         return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         return null;
      }
   }
}

public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {   column};
    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, it is working when selecting file from other folders in Android device

Please advise. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For now, the best approach for getting path is :

Getting physical file from URI as InputStream,
`ContentResolver.openInputStream()` allow you to access the contents of a file without knowing its real path

```
String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

then write it as a temporary file in cached storage

```
File file = new File(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+id);
writeFile(inputStream, file);
String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

> Here is the method to write temporary file into cached storage

```
void writeFile(InputStream in, File file) {
     OutputStream out = null;
     try {
          out = new FileOutputStream(file);
          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
          int len;
          while((len=in.read(buf))>0){
            out.write(buf,0,len);
          }
     } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
     finally {
          try {
            if ( out != null ) {
                 out.close();
            }
            in.close();
          } catch ( IOException e ) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
}
```

Not sure if its the best way to do, but the code is working properly :D

Comment: But it still doesn't give you the real file path.

Comment: This is a life-saving solution. Thanks. But am still wondering why the google guys can't keep it simple. I think this is a lot of work just to get a file path.

Comment: @ryosu just left an answer, which is less complex - and it returns the actual path.

Comment: @ryosu Its working fine till Android N, but in Android P it's not working when picking images from Downloads folder, and crashing. Can you suggest any other way for the same.

Answer (score 4):

> this is activity instance variable

```
*************************************************************************
*************************************************************************  

    Uri filePath;
    String strAttachmentFileName = "",//attached file name
            strAttachmentCoded = "";//attached file in byte code Base64
    int PICK_REQUEST =1;
*************************************************************************
*************************************************************************
```

> this is in activity method

```
*************************************************************************
*************************************************************************  

Button buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("file/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select any file"), PICK_REQUEST );
            }
        });
*************************************************************************
*************************************************************************
```

> this is overrride activity method

```
*************************************************************************
*************************************************************************



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            File uploadFile = new File(FileUtils.getRealPath(activity.this, filePath));
            try {
                if (uploadFile != null) {
                    strAttachmentFileName = uploadFile.getName();
                    FileInputStream objFileIS = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream objByteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] byteBufferString = new byte[1024];
                    int readNum;
                    readNum = objFileIS.read(byteBufferString);
                    while (readNum != -1) {
                        objByteArrayOS.write(byteBufferString, 0, readNum);
                        readNum = objFileIS.read(byteBufferString);
                    }
                    strAttachmentCoded  = Base64.encodeToString(objByteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

*************************************************************************
*************************************************************************
```

> Please create file FileUtils.java as below

[link HBiSoft](https://gist.github.com/HBiSoft/15899990b8cd0723c3a894c1636550a8)

---

---

For Any Type of File in .Net  ---

```
byte[] p = Convert.FromBase64String("byte string");

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(p);
FileStream fs = new FileStream
        (System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ComplaintDetailsFile/") +
                item.FileName, FileMode.Create);
ms.WriteTo(fs);
ms.Close();
fs.Close();
fs.Dispose();
```

Comment: perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution that I found from this gist. [FileUtils.java](https://gist.github.com/HBiSoft/15899990b8cd0723c3a894c1636550a8)

Here is how to use it.

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    File originalFile = new File(FileUtils.getRealPath(this,uri));
}
```

Comment: i dont know why give 'answer not full'  for this answer, but this is usefull for me, thanks @nimrod-mania

Answer (score 1):

Below API will be useful.We need to create file in our app's cache and return the same path because of restrictions i.e **Scoped storage.**

```
fun createFileAndGetPathFromCacheFolder(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    var inputStream: FileInputStream? = null
    var outputStream: FileOutputStream? = null
    try {
        val parcelFileDescriptor = context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r", null)
        inputStream = FileInputStream(parcelFileDescriptor?.fileDescriptor)
        val file = File(context.cacheDir, context.contentResolver.getFileName(uri))
        outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var len: Int
        while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { len = it } != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len)
        }
        return file.absolutePath
    } catch (e: Exception) {

    } finally {
        inputStream?.close()
        outputStream?.close()
    }
    return " "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've just came up with (it's tested on Android Pie & is assuming a SD Card):

```
private String getParentDirectory(@NonNull Uri uri) {
    String uriPath = uri.getPath();
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    if(uriPath != null) {filePath = new File(filePath.concat("/" + uriPath.split(":")[1])).getParent();}
    return filePath;
}

private String getAbsolutePath(@NonNull Uri uri) {
    String uriPath = uri.getPath();
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    if(uriPath != null) {filePath = filePath.concat("/" + uriPath.split(":")[1]);}
    return filePath;
}
```