# Get real path from URI? Android 9+

Tags: java, android

I have the uri of my files. Now I need to get its real path to send them. (the uri is like: "content://some-path").

This is for Android 9

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52814247/3518278

Comment: Why do you need the file path?

Comment: @PPartisan to make a POST Multipart request

Comment: What library/functions are you trying to use to make a POST Multipart request, as they are likely to be able to take a `FileDescriptor` object instead of a filename, which you can get with Android 9+

Comment: @Andrew Retrofit 2, but I need the path to be able to send the file!

Answer (score 1):

So with Android 9+ you can only use file paths inside you applications private storage area otherwise you have to use URI's and `ContentResolver`s

See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped for details of the changes in 9+

So I see three solutions when using Retrofit2

1. Get a Java `FileDescriptor` from a contentResolver and read the file from the contentResolver, writing it to your App's private storage area. You can then get a Java File Object as normal from this copy of the file. This is similar to  [stackoverflow.com/a/52814247/3518278](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52814247/3518278) as suggested by ViVekH
2. Get a Java `FileDescriptor` from a contentResolver and read it in to a in memory Byte array. I'm not a Retrofit2 user but I believe you can create Request Body or Multipart part from a Byte array instead of a Java `File` object.
3. Raise a feature request with RetroFit2 / OKHTTP to be able to give it a Java `FileDescriptor` object instead of a `File` Object

Note with the `contentResolver` you can query it to get the "Display Name" as the filename part of the Path.